# Find the mean and standard deviation of the distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, standard-deviation

Hypothetically seen if I had to find the mean and standard deviation of the distribution for this question. How would I get to that?

“A basketball player is traditionally a 73% foul shooter. In a season, he takes 428 foul shots. Find the mean and standard deviation of the distribution”

I've been trying to figure it out but I seem to be getting the wrong answer every time

Comment: Look up *binomial distribution*.

Comment: I suggest doing more research into the sort of thing that might model a shooting percentage with equal probability regardless of the previous shots. Or if you don't want to research it, consider how you might model the probability of getting exactly $k$ baskets out of $n$ shots.

Answer (score 0):

The mean and variance of a binomial distribution, ${\cal B}(n,p)$, for $n$ samples with success rate $p$ is a classic problem in statistics:

${\rm mean} = n p = 312.44$

${\rm variance} = n (1-p) p = 84.3588$, and the standard deviation is merely the square root of the variance, $9.1847$.

[image]

Comment: Wow mind if I ask how u got to it?

Comment: This result is in every book on statistics and distributions.